# Create own bib style with makebst, need avoid brackets for citations which are already put into bracket

Tags: bibtex, citing, custom-bib, multiple-citations

ich create a bib style for my thesis.
Is it possible to tell latex to put brackets for the data if there is directly in the text, and no brackets if the citation is already in a bracket?
I don't want to have two brackets at the begin and the end, see figure

[image]

Thanks a lot!
Yao

Answer (score 1):

I found it ! I should just use \citep!